# redirect from global.asax not working in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I can't seem to redirect from the Application_BeginRequest in my asp.net mvc site. I'm not sure why this isn't working... I suspect routing, but not exactly sure why.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Application_BeginRequest
    /// </summary>
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
         Response.Redirect("siteoffline.html");                     
    }
```

Firefox display this message when I try

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the
request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redirecting inside `Application_BeginRequest` which is invoked for **each** request. So when your application runs `Application_BeginRequest` is triggered and you redirect to `siteoffline.html` and when this page is served, `Application_BeginRequest` is triggered and you redirect to `siteoffline.html` and you get the point of the infinite loop. Fortunately FireFox stops this madness after it detects that you are abusing too much with redirects.

Conclusion: never redirect to a page that is part of your web site inside the `Application_BeginRequest` event, it's like shooting yourself into the foot.

By the way for putting your site in maintenance mode you probably want to use an [app_offline.htm file](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx) as blogged by the Gu instead of reinventing wheels.